# Issue with jQuery on function and animationstart/animationend events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, 3d, css-animations

I am trying to make some 3D animations I have working on `web-kit` browsers to work on other browsers, too.

Firstly, I have changed the `css` a little bit to be valid for other browsers, too (I know that some of the `css` rules are working only on latest browsers versions - `IE` for example):

```
.container
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d
  transform-style: preserve-3d

.front
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden
  backface-visibility: hidden

.back
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden
  backface-visibility: hidden

  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -180deg)
  transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -180deg)

.show .container

  -webkit-animation: test 1s ease-in-out forwards
  -moz-animation: test 1s ease-in-out forwards
  -o-animation: test 1s ease-in-out forwards
  animation: test 1s ease-in-out forwards

@-webkit-keyframes test
  0%
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0)
  100%
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -180deg)

@keyframes test
  0%
    -moz-transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0)
    -o-transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0)
    transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0)
  100%
    -moz-transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -180deg)
    -o-transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -180deg)
    transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -180deg)
```

I know the `css` may tell nothing - I am just showing what I have added to make it valid for not `webkit` browsers, too.

My animation is not working on `Firefox 28` on `Ubuntu 13.10`. What I have found is that the code binding on animation start event is not executed:

```
this.testElement.on({

                    'animationstart webkitAnimationStart oAnimationStart MSAnimationStart': $.proxy(function(){
                     ....
                    }, this),
                    'animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd':  $.proxy(function(){
                     ....
                    }, this)
                });
```

As I have said, the animations are working in `Chrome`, but not in browsers that are not from `web-kit` family. Since, I am copping the animations start and end events from [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/) I guess, there is something wrong with my `css`.

Could anyone advice what should I try?

Answer (score 1):

A keyframes rule can not mix vendor specific styles; *all* the content must be valid for a specific browser.

So,

```
@keyframes test
  0%
    -moz-transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0)
    -o-transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0)
    transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0)
  100%
    -moz-transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -180deg)
    -o-transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -180deg)
    transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -180deg)
```

isn't valid. write it in 3 different rules

```
@keyframes test {
    0% { transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0) }
  100% { transition: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -180deg) }
}
```

and so on.

the event binding will come later, once you have your animation working :-)